# Fixing "warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublickKey._fastmath" error on Python 2.7 with CentOS 6.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, centos6

I'm running a CentOS 6.4 server with Python 2.7 (installed via PythonBrew script)

I have gmp installed via 'yum install gmp'
and python-devel installed via 'yum install python-devel' (but it's for python 2.6 series)

I'm trying to install pycrypto on my server, but it's giving me

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublickKey._fastmath
```

Is there any way to make pip 'recognize' my gmp installation?

Thanks : D

Answer (score 10):

I got the above error when trying to install Fabric at the system level on Centos 6.4 using pip.  (Fabric uses pycrypto).

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublickKey._fastmath
```

This is how I got it working:

```
yum install gmp-devel
sudo pip uninstall ecdsa pycrypto paramiko fabric 
# clear out the pip build dirs
rm -rf /tmp/pip-*
# make sure the directory containing libgmp.so.3 is on the python path
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"  
pip install fabric
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a step-by-step I've just made up on my CentOS server (the sequence assumes you're not root):

**LIBGMP INSTALL**

Firstly, setup and install libgmp somewhere in your home directory, as follows:

```
./configure prefix=$HOME
make
make install prefix=$HOME
```

This will create a ~/lib, a ~/include and a ~/share directory if not existing already.

Then, add the following line to your .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Do a ". ~/.bashrc" to enforce your changes.

**PYCRYPTO BUILD & INSTALL**

We need to deal with the install process manually.
Firstly, we may download pycrypto as follows:

- go into a directory where you store your sources:

  cd ~/src
- download pycrypto source archive:

  curl -o pycrypto.tar.gz "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.6.tar.gz#md5=88dad0a270d1fe83a39e0467a66a22bb"
- uncompress + untar archive:

  gunzip pycrypto.tar.gz
  tar xvf pycrypto.tar

Then we need to cheat the configuration "a bit":

```
cd pycrypto-26
./configure --includedir=$HOME/include
```

- Edit the file cd src/config.h and amend the values for the
  definitions:

  #define HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM 0              instead of 1

  #define HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC 1          instead of 0

  #define HAVE_LIBGMP 1                     instead of 0
- Then edit the setup.py file by searching for the keyword "_fastmath"
  and ensure that the Extension() declaration looks as per below:

  ```
  Extension("Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath",
            include_dirs=['/home/<yourhome>/include','src/','/usr/include/'],
            library_dirs=['/home/<yourhome>/lib'],
            libraries=['gmp'],
            sources=["src/_fastmath.c"]),
  ```

Finally, build pycrypto with:

```
python setup.py build
```

You should see somewhere in the trace the following line:

```
...
building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension
...
```

You can then do a "python setup.py install" or, if like me you prefer pip:

```
cd ..
pip install ./pycrypto-2.6
```

Then you should get no error when executing the following lines from python:

```
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import _fastmath
>>> import Crypto.Random
>>> _fastmath.HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC
1
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably need gmp-devel installed, too.  This gives pycrypto the headers it needs to build using libgmp.

On Ubuntu, I only had libgmp10 installed.  I hit the same warning when trying to install pycrypto.  After installing the Ubuntu package libgmp-dev, the warning went away and the build script indicated it was using the _fastmath extension.

If you already installed pycrypto without _fastmath, you can reinstall it with the -I flag, e.g.

`sudo pip install -I pycrypto`

Answer (score 4):

Just for anyone who runs across this in recent years, as I am sure there are/will be some. I was able to easily fix this issue on my Debian Jessie install by running the following command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Then try your install again. In my case I was trying to install ansible via pip with the following command. *Also for those to be able to come across this post with same scenario.*

```
$ sudo pip install ansible
```

The output should now be the following.

```
Successfully installed pycrypto
Cleaning up...
```

I hope this helps someone down the road! 
- justin

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the C++ libraries to build this. Install VS 2017
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017