# Trying to install pycrypto on Mac OSX mavericks

Tags: python, macos, pycrypto

I am currently trying to install pycrypto and when I execute python setup.py build I receive this following error:

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so
ld: illegal text-relocation to '___gmp_binvert_limb_table' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from '___gmpn_divexact_1' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've already tried reinstalling the command line tools and removing old instances of Xcode.

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 35):

This worked for me. (Should work if you are on Xcode 5.1)

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: For others; if using buildout you can use the [environment] tag, or simply run python bootstrap.py && ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bin/buildout

Comment: not working. `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 12):

This did it for me:

```
  sudo port install gmp
  sudo ln -s  /opt/local/lib/libgmp.dylib  /usr/lib/libgmp.dylib  
  ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include sudo -E pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Using the last line worked for me, even without the first two.

Comment: You can use `LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib` instead of linking libgmp. Not sure if it's actually safer, since you might link with other libs from /opt/local though.

Comment: what worked for me on El Capitan was `brew install gmp` and `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.0/lib/ pip install pycrypto` (you might need to change gmp dir version)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue and was able to fix it by installing gmp:

```
brew install gmp
```

Then I nuked my build directory and started over with the pycrypto install and it succeeded.

This also fixes the warning message during pycrypto's configure script:

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublickKey._fastmath
```

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319033/fixing-warning-gmp-or-mpir-library-not-found-not-building-crypto-publickkey).

Answer (score 9):

On Yosemite:

```
CC=clang sudo -E pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` -- my script still can't find PyCrypto

Comment: Sounds like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: could be....`PYTHONPATH` is null. I already solved it by doing `easy_install` for pyCrypto

Answer (score 8):

This works on Mojave and is better IMO than the other presented options:

`brew install gmp
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include \
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib \
pip install pycrypto`

Comment: Worked on Monterey (12.2.1) for me.

Answer (score 3):

on El Capitan I just did this ...

```
sudo easy_install livestreamer
sudo easy_install PyCrypto
```

et voila... I can now save streams to my HDD.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed recently that **I needed brew to install gmp** to get pip install pycrypto working again after upgrading OSX 10.9 and Xcode 5. But then the gmp build started failing on illegal text-relocation. It seems [a known issue 12946](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12946) causes the compiler to fail compiling position independent code:

> cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F.
>   -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o
>   build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so
>
> ld: illegal text-relocation to '___gmp_binvert_limb_table' in
>   /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from '___gmpn_divexact_1' in
>   /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Similar to the answer provided by [radiofrequency](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156196/radiofrequency) I symlinked the shared library of gmp into the system's /usr/lib directory as a workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/5.1.3/lib/libgmp.dylib /usr/lib/libgmp.dylib
```

The gmp developer should add --with-pic.

Side point: the number of warnings building pycrypto does not provide comfort.

Comment: This worked for me. Obviously the version of gmp needs to be changed depending on the one installed on the machine. In my case I substituted 5.1.3 with 6.0.0a. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you also looking to install pycrypto as well as the cryptography package, this is the command that ended up working for me:

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install cryptography`

Answer (score 1):

For installation of PyCrypto use MacPorts and following command. I tested it on the newest version of Mac OS X - Yosemite:

Python Version 2.7:

```
sudo port install py27-crypto
```

Python Version 3.4:

```
sudo port install py34-crypto
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me on Mac/El Capitan:

`sudo easy_install -U livestreamer`

Answer (score 1):

To install pycrypto run the following command

```
$ CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

[Install homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (single line for installation at bottom of page), then try:

```
$ sudo pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Did you install homebrew?

Comment: intall home brew, then what?

Comment: Then the thing in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, pip and homebrew are both package managers, but homebrew is built on ruby and pip is built on python.

```
$ sudo pip install pycrypto
```

This command you referred to needs pip installed, not homebrew.

[This way to get pip](http://pip-installer.org)

Comment: If you do not have pip installed already, then you can install it first with `sudo python -m ensurepip`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new comer to python; I experienced this problem also; and it vexed me. None of the solutions posted worked for me, so I archived `libgmp.a` and `libgmp.la` temporarily, and `pip` then installed `Crypto` without error. Is this an acceptable approach? I have *no* understanding as to why this worked...