# OS X Pillow installation error

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I followed this instructions: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation

```
$ sudo pip install Pillow
```

returned error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bAG3wP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /var/root/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

in `pip.log`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-bAG3wP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
```

Please, help me!

UPDATE:

I installed PIL before. After installation I tried some black magic to make PIL work with libjpeg. And then I tried to reinstall PIL. It was uninstalled, but failed to install.

Comment: It looks like you are not able to compile it. Are you on OSX 10.9? There are a few topics about the same problem. Try to install/update your xcode with `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: yes, 10.9. Should I reinstall xcode? It is up to date now.

Comment: i tried `xcode-select --install` and press `Update`. It returned error: `Unable to install, because update is unavailable through update server` (loose translation from Russian)

Comment: I don't really know, it just happened to some people after updating to 10.9 and updating xcode solved it fur me, but apparently the answer below solved your problem! Good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be something broken when running XCode 5.1. Had the same problem when [installing pycrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617686/trying-to-install-pycrypto-on-mac-osx-mavericks/22424999#22424999).

Try this:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install Pillow
```