# Installing igraph on OS X Mavericks

Tags: r, macos, igraph

I'm having trouble installing igraph on R 3.1.0 on OS X Mavericks with XCode 5.1.1.  The error message I get is:

```
ld: illegal text-relocation to '___gmp_binvert_limb_table' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from '___gmpn_divexact_1' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [igraph.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
```

Looking around, I found that I'm not the only one to have this issue and it's not limited to igraph ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617686/trying-to-install-pycrypto-on-mac-osx-mavericks) and [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12946)), but adding `CXXFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` to `~/.R/Makevars` didn't help. From the error message, it looks like R found the system installation of GMP and not the Macports version, which could conceivably have been built for a different architecture. (Installing from binaries also didn't work for me, with an error message of `image not found`, but it looks like this is a [separate issue](http://vegan.r-forge.r-project.org/FAQ-R-Forge.html).)  Has anyone else encountered similar issues?

`sessionInfo()` gives:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2 (64-bit)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same config as you do and `igraph` v0.7.0 (binary) installs fine with `install.packages()`. v0.7.1 (source) install did not work at all but was/is due to a `quadmath` lib error.

Comment: You can try downloading the binary from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html (the one for Snow Leopard if you need 0.7.1).

Comment: Btw. if you are building R with MacPorts, that is not supported, so you are on your own.

Comment: No, I built R from scratch.  That was my first thought.

Comment: I tried installing v0.6.6 from source, and got the same error.  Installing from binary appears to work, but when I `require` igraph, I get an `image not found` error and it won't load.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason for building R, I suggest using the Snow Leopard installer they provide. The binary packages on CRAN and igraph.org are compatible with that, but not necessarily compatible with your build.

Comment: Great!  Reinstalling R from source let me use the R binaries.  If you want to add your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is helpful to anyone else, here is the solution from Gabor Csardi that worked for me:  Try with the binary distribution of R.  I had built R from source, and that version didn't work with installing igraph from either source or binary.