# How to install pycrypto _fastmath.so in the correct place

Tags: python-2.7, gmp, pycrypto

My question is how can I configure the installation of pycrypto so _fastmath gets put into the correct place.

I have followed the instructions in this excellent SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319033/fixing-warning-gmp-or-mpir-library-not-found-not-building-crypto-publickkey/18473535#18473535). However, I cannot get past this error and need some help.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. Did you install a recent version of libgmp?

Comment: Yes. I followed all those instructions. I did get the latest library of gmp.